# Execute jdbc call in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

In spring mvc when i execute the following command it shows error.

`Map<String,Object> out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);`

The error is :
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.commonDatabaseName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataProviderFactory$1.processMetaData(CallMetaDataProviderFactory.java:73)`

Please help. I am stucked with this problem for last 2 days but still did not find any solution.

Comment: which version of spring-jdbc you are using?

Comment: spring-jdbc- 3.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: try to change to 4.x.x.RELEASE and check. Nosuchmethoderror means that method not there in your classpath while compile time .

Comment: I have changed it to 4.2.1 RELEASE  but still facing same problem

Comment: Do you use Maven? If so, please post the output of `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: Can you please post the complete code related to `simpleJdbcCall` including the autowiring

Comment: `@Autowired public void setDataSource(BasicDataSource dataSource) {this.simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("read");
this. simpleJdbcCall.declareParameters(new SqlParameter("@field1", Types.VARCHAR));
}  public List<User> getUser(int id){
List<User> user = new ArrayList<User>();
SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("@field1",String.valueOf(id));
Map<String,Object> out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
User comp = new User();
comp.setName((String)out.get("Field1"));
comp.setAge((String)out.get("Field2"));
user.add(comp);
return user; }` @Jay

Answer (score 2):

There may the few cases where you can find `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`. Here I am summarising few of them according to your issue.

1. The `NoSuchMethodError` error is thrown when the referenced class
   used to compile the code and the class in the classpath are
   different. This error occur at runtime, if the definition of a class
   has incompatibly changed. The user must check for this error, in
   cases the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.
2. `NoSuchMethodError` error can be thrown when an application makes use of external libraries. Suppose your application is compiled and executed using a specific version of an external library. At some point, the external library is changed and some methods are removed or updated. If the classpath of your application is not updated and your code is not compiled using the latest version of the external library, then during runtime you will invoke a method that no longer exists and the `NoSuchMethodError` error will be thrown.

So, when you compile your application be sure that your classpath contains the appropriate source and .jar files, and that you have the latest version of each one.

So, solution for your problem is check the version of .jar you are using. For this you can use maven dependency trees or you can have look at maven repositories.